# Replace string (3-11-2012) with other date format (3 november 2012)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui

I have text strings like '11-1-2012' and I'd like that to convert into date strings like '11 januari 2012'. How do I do this? I searched but could not find exactly what I need. The dates (month names) need to be in Dutch. I tried using datepicker doing something like

```
$(".txtToDate").datepicker.parseDate( "d MM yy", "1 november 2001" );
```

but that doesn't work. JavaScript or jQuery is what I prefer...

thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are so many ways to solve this.**

Here's the final solution working for each month. Hope it helps :)

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("txtToDate");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var userMonth = elements[i].innerHTML;
  var updatedText =  myFunction(userMonth);
  elements[i].innerHTML = updatedText;
}

function myFunction(str){

var currentMonth = '';
var months = ["januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni", "juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"];

var arr = str.split("-");
var num = arr[1];

currentMonth = (num.startsWith("0")) ? num.slice(1) : num;
customizedMonth = months[currentMonth - 1];
var text = arr[0] + " " + customizedMonth  + " " + arr[2];

return text;
}
```

```html
<div class = "txtToDate">11-01-2012</div>
<div class = "txtToDate">11-02-2012</div>
<div class = "txtToDate">11-03-2012</div>
<div class = "txtToDate">11-04-2012</div>
<div class = "txtToDate">11-05-2012</div>
<div class = "txtToDate">11-06-2012</div>
<div class = "txtToDate">11-07-2012</div>
<div class = "txtToDate">11-08-2012</div>
<div class = "txtToDate">11-09-2012</div>
<div class = "txtToDate">11-10-2012</div>
<div class = "txtToDate">11-11-2012</div>
<div class = "txtToDate">11-12-2012</div>
```

Comment: tnx Henry. Do you think I can replace the var str with a class? Like in: (.txtToDate)? I need to replace every instance within the div.txtToDate tag with you solution. It are not current dates...

Comment: <script>
 var string = '3-11-2002';
 console.log(string.replace(/-(\d{2})-/, function (a, b) { 
 return ' ' + { '10': 'oktober','11': 'november' }[b] + ' ';
}));
</script>

Comment: <script>
      var str = '3-11-2002'; 
      var currentMonth = '';
      var months = ["januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni", "juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"];
      var arr = str.split("-");
      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
       if(arr[i].startsWith("0")){
        currentMonth = arr[i].slice(1);
       }
      }
      if(currentMonth === "1"){
         currentMonth = months[currentMonth - 1];
      }
      var text = arr[0] + " " + currentMonth + " " + arr[2];
      console.log(text)
                    </script>

Comment: @KestonPollard I think I got it working. Are you there?

Comment: Yes I am here. seems that oktober, november and december don't work. (10,11,12)

Comment: @KestonPollard remember that index of januari is 0 and index of december is 11 ...NOT 12

Comment: @KestonPollard I have updated my answer :).Everything is working fine now. Please mark my answer as the correct one and vote it up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple solution:

```js
function returnCorrectDate(inputDate) {

  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var arrayDate = inputDate.split("-");

  return arrayDate[0] + " " + months[parseInt(arrayDate[1]) - 1] + " " + arrayDate[2];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object for the month names and the replacing.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("txtToDate");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(item) {
    var date = item.innerHTML.split('-');
    date[1] = date[1].replace(/\d{2}/, function (month) { 
        return { '01': 'januari', '02': 'februari', '03': 'maart', '04': 'april', '05': 'mei', '06': 'juni', '07': 'juli', '08': 'augustus', '09': 'september', '10': 'oktober', '11': 'november', '12': 'december' }[month];
    });
    item.innerHTML = date.join(' ');
});
```

```html
<div class="txtToDate">11-01-2012</div>
<div class="txtToDate">11-02-2012</div>
<div class="txtToDate">11-03-2012</div>
<div class="txtToDate">11-04-2012</div>
<div class="txtToDate">11-05-2012</div>
<div class="txtToDate">11-06-2012</div>
<div class="txtToDate">11-07-2012</div>
<div class="txtToDate">11-08-2012</div>
<div class="txtToDate">11-09-2012</div>
<div class="txtToDate">11-10-2012</div>
<div class="txtToDate">11-11-2012</div>
<div class="txtToDate">11-12-2012</div>
```

Comment: Tnx,I tried this (because I need to read the value of every div with class .txtToDate. 
'var string = $(".txtToDate");
console.log(string.replace(/-(\d{2})-/, function (a, b) { 
    return ' ' + { '10': 'oktober','11': 'november' }[b] + ' ';
}));' but this gets an error

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
var dateArr = '11-01-2012'.split('-');
var month;
switch(dataArr[1]){
   case '01':
      month = 'januari';
      break;
  //other cases
}
var dateStr = dateArr[0] + month + dateArr[2];
return dateStr;
```